# How to add object element in array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have static array constant of objects something similar to below.

```
export const EMPLOYEES = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: ‘John’,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: ‘Doe’,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: ‘Bull’,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: ‘Scott’,
  },
];
```

Now I need to add the last element only based on if some condition is true. Some this like if `isAmerican()` is true.

Can somebody help me here how to add element based on the condition? Thanks.

Comment: Can't modify constants like that.

Comment: You can't modify what the constant points to, but you can push to the array. So do something like:

    if (isAmerican()) {
        employees.push({
             id: 6,
             name: 'Timmy'
        })
    }

Comment: `Now I need to have the last element only based on if some condition is true.` What do you mean by `have`? Remove? Get?

Comment: @FrankerZ Sure you can, nothing in `const` makes the array immutable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it using spread operator:

```
export const EMPLOYEES = [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Doe",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Bull",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Scott",
    },
    ... isAmerican() ? [{ id: 6, name: "Jemmy"}] : []
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** modify (or try to modify) a constant. I can see two ways you can do this:

1. Create a pure function to return a new constant with the new object added to the array
2. Use a spread operator in the definition of the constant

**Option 1: Pure function**

```
function makeNewArray(array, objectToAppend, isAmerican) {
    return isAmerican ? [...array, objectToAppend] : array
}

const EMPLOYEES = [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Doe",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Bull",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Scott",
    }
];

const arrayWithAmerican = makeNewArray(EMPLOYEES, { id: 6, name: "American Frank"}, true);
const arrayWithoutAmerican = makeNewArray(EMPLOYEES, { id: 6, name: "Not American Frank"}, false);

console.log(arrayWithAmerican);
console.log(arrayWithoutAmerican);
```

**Option 2: Spread operator**

```
function isAmerican(){
    // generic code here.
    return true;
}

const EMPLOYEES = [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Doe",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Bull",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Scott",
    },
    ... isAmerican() ? [{ id: 6, name: "American Frank"}] : []
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the condition will be fulfilled, simply push an object to your EMPLOYEES array:

```
let isAmerican = true;

const EMPLOYEES = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Doe",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Bull",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Scott",
  },
];

if(isAmerican) {
    EMPLOYEES.push({
    id: 6,
    name: "Frank"
  })
}
console.log(EMPLOYEES)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rqx35pLz/